# "Bad promise" error after throwing an exception from the thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I have a function that should be put in a thread that may through exception.
After throwing an exception from the thread function I get an error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
  what():  Broken promise
```

Function worked fine until it thought an exception. Tried not to use future and make everything with promise but it didn't help.
Here is my simplified code:

```
    ...

    using namespace std;


    void MyFunc(struct ForThread_struct for_thread, promise<const char *> && s_Promise);
    main(){

      promise<const char *> v_promise[5];
      future<const char *> v_future[5];
      thread a_Threads[5];

    for (int_fast8_t k = 0; k < 5; k++ ) {
    v_future[k] = v_promise[k].get_future();
    a_Threads[k] = thread(MyFunc, for_thread[k], move(v_promise[k]));
    }
     for (int_fast8_t k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {
         try {

            const char * res = v_future[k].get();

         }

        catch(exception & e)
        {
         cout<<e.what()<<endl;
        }
    }
void MyFunc(struct ForThread_struct for_thread, promise<const char *> && s_Promise)

  {

    try{
        if (for_thread.var == 0){
                throw runtime_error("ERROR");
         }
         else{
         throw runtime_error("FINE");
         }
       }
catch(...) {
        s_Promise.set_exception(current_exception());
       }

  }
```

Interesting thing is that according to debugger nothing is thrown from `MyFunc` exception is thrown from the `main` thread

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? Presumably before your `try` block, but your debugger should show you exactly where.

Comment: Why do you even add the `main` to the example, when you don't even add `nNumThread`, `for_func`. Obviously `nNumThread` must be `5` though.

Comment: @Useless I modified code!

Comment: @AϟϟTERIX `for_func` and `nNumThread` is still nowhere to be found. As well as `ForThread_struct`.

Comment: made an update to my answer - implemented in terms of std::async. You might find that interesting.

Comment: could not reproduce a `std::future_error` with your code, only got a terminate when thread destructor called before the thread has being detached or joined.

Comment: `int_fast8_t` for loop control? Just use `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise is going out of scope. You need to take ownership of it within the thread's function.

This fixes it (plus the other issues that prevented compilation):

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct ForThread_struct {
    int var = 0;
};

void MyFunc(struct ForThread_struct for_thread, promise<const char *>  s_Promise);

int main()
{
    ForThread_struct for_thread[5] = {};

    promise<const char *> v_promise[5];
    future<const char *> v_future[5];
    thread a_Threads[5];

    for (int_fast8_t k = 0; k < 5; k++ ) {
        v_future[k] = v_promise[k].get_future();
        a_Threads[k] = thread(MyFunc, for_thread[k], move(v_promise[k]));
    }
    for (int_fast8_t k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {
        try {

            const char * res = v_future[k].get();

        }

        catch(exception & e)
        {
            cout<<e.what()<<endl;
        }
    }

    for (auto& t : a_Threads) {
        if (t.joinable()) t.join();
    }
}

void MyFunc(struct ForThread_struct for_thread, promise<const char *> s_Promise)

{


    try{
        if (for_thread.var == 0){
            throw runtime_error("ERROR");
        }
        else{
            throw runtime_error("FINE");
        }
    }
    catch(...) {
        s_Promise.set_exception(current_exception());
    }

}
```

expected output:

```
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
```

Although this version of MyFunc might make more sense (and is a little easier on the eyes IMHO):

```
void MyFunc(struct ForThread_struct for_thread, promise<const char *> s_Promise)
try
{
    if (for_thread.var == 0) {
        throw runtime_error("ERROR");
    }
    s_Promise.set_value("FINE");
}
catch(...) {
    s_Promise.set_exception(current_exception());
}
```

Update:

FYI, the STL library implementors have already done the hard work for you with `packaged_task<>` and `std::async<>()`.

Your program might arguably be more idiomatically implemented thus:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


struct ForThread_struct {
    int var = 0;
};

const char* MyFunc(struct ForThread_struct for_thread)
{
    if (for_thread.var == 0) {
        throw runtime_error("ERROR");
    }
    return "FINE";
}


int main()
{
    ForThread_struct all_structs[] = {
        { 0 },
        { 1 },
        { 0 },
        { 2 },
        { 0 }
    };

    std::vector<std::future<const char *>> futures;

    for (const auto& ts : all_structs)
    {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async,
                                     &MyFunc,
                                     ts));
    }

    for (auto& f : futures)
    {
        try
        {
            const char * res = f.get();
            std::cout << res << std::endl;
        }
        catch(exception & e)
        {
            cout<<e.what()<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
ERROR
FINE
ERROR
FINE
ERROR
```